# Java heap space error in TypeDB when importing CSV files

Tags: csv, import, vaticle-typedb

I tried to import some CSV files into my TypeDB schema using Python and got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\Desktop\test\migrate.py", line 65, in <module>
    build_test_graph(inputs=inputs)
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\Desktop\test\migrate.py", line 9, in build_test_graph
    load_data_into_typedb(input, session)
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\Desktop\test\migrate.py", line 21, in load_data_into_typedb
    transaction.commit()
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typedb\connection\transaction.py", line 95, in commit
    self.execute(transaction_commit_req())
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typedb\connection\transaction.py", line 80, in execute
    return self.run_query(request, batch).get()
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typedb\stream\bidirectional_stream.py", line 136, in get
    return self._stream.fetch(self._request_id)
  File "C:\Users\panxx006\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\typedb\stream\bidirectional_stream.py", line 84, in fetch
    raise error
typedb.common.exception.TypeDBClientException: Java heap space

Please check server logs for the stack trace.
```

Could you please tell me the way to fix this error? I'm using TypeDB 2.6.3

Comment: Hi Sonali, could you post the code you are using to run the import? Additionally, you should know that TypeDB version 2.13.0 is now available. It has multiple improvements regarding memory usage.

Comment: Hi James, Thank you for your response. When I used the newest version (2.13.0) this error didn't come up.

Comment: Glad to hear! I'll give this as the answer so it's more visible to other users in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading your version of TypeDB to the latest version will help solve this error. As of writing, TypeDB 2.13.0 is the newest version, which includes a number of improvements to memory usage so you should see fewer errors of this kind in the future.

You can download the latest version of TypeDB from the releases page on GitHub: https://github.com/vaticle/typedb/releases

Full disclosure: I work for Vaticle, the creators of TypeDB.